# Sample among any axis on a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following piece of code:

```
if axis == 0:
    return m[idx, :]
elif axis == 1:
    return m[:, idx]
else:
    raise('Argument axis currently accepts only values 0 and 1.')
```

How to generalize this behaviour for any shape and any value of `axis`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
return np.take(m, idx, axis=axis)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use rollaxis function in numpy package.
Example code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.arange(30).reshape([5, 6])
print(numpy.rollaxis(a, 0)[1])
```

It prints out the the second element in the first axis.